# How to configure VSTO application on a client

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto

In my Visual Studio VSTO solution, I can configure my add-in (WCF endpoints for instance) in my app.config file. How can I configure my add-in once deployed on a client site ?

I cannot set my service location before.

Comment: whats the problem, cant you ship your app.config to client machine and do autoupdate for any change in configuration

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which application the add-in is for, so I will assume it is Excel (the instructions should be the same for any office app, so just replace Excel.exe with the app you are developing for).

You should add the config sections from the app.config file to Excel's app.config file, since excel is the application running the add-in.

The file should be called Excel.exe.config, and it should be located in the same directory as Excel.exe (the folder location will of course depend on your version of office). If the config file doesn't already exist you can create it.